# Publishing of features in ArcGIS Server

Tags: arcgis-server

I am a very green when it comes to publishing features and tools in ArcGIS Server. Do I need to know any other programming language apart from Python. My final aim was to come up with a service that can be accessed via any web browser and used by people who have no GIS background to carry out buffering.

Comment: Python is fine for the back end, but for GUIs you'd  be better off learning HTML/JavaScript.

Comment: You don't need any programming skills to publish a service and spin up a web app using either one of the configurable templates or Web AppBuilder with ArcGIS Server.  http://www.esri.com/videos/watch?videoid=qEJ7TX_ixEs&channelid=UC_yE3TatdZKAXvt_TzGJ6mw&title=arcgis-apps:-web-appbuilder-for-arcgis:-build-web-apps-with-no-coding